# How to Send Sms from desktop application

Tags: c#

Can anybody tell me that how a message will send on phone from a desktop application. I have a module in which i have to send sms to my user's mobile i do not how it is possible can anybody tell how this is possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we use mobile phone for sending message from desktop application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379251/can-we-use-mobile-phone-for-sending-message-from-desktop-application)

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into 3rd party software, for example: http://www.textanywhere.net/

Note: these are paid services.

Comment: @Jonathan Bick can you please tell me that how gateway is handle or what i can do for embed the gateway in my desktop app ... can you briefly describe me about this all logic ?

Comment: You can find all details about the API etc here: http://www.textanywhere.net/developers/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need some kind of **sms gateway** in order to achieve this but gateways are not free they are paid services. how ever you can also use **gsm modem** to achieve this.

Comment: can you please tell me that how gateway is handle or what i can do for embed the gateway in my desktop app ... can you briefly describe me about this all logic ?

Comment: gateway is just an api that service provider will provide you . you just have to call methods. in order to use service you need some kind of authentication and for this you need to purchase credentials.